# Jquery. Call a function when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, prototype

**Given:** There is a JS function that calls the list of cities. Included in the **header** as a **js** file

```
GeoIPModule.prototype.loadCities = function(callback) {
        var self = this;
        if (!this.citiesLoaded) {
            $.ajax({
                url:      self.http_host + 'index.php?route=extension/module/geoip/getList',
                dataType: 'html',
                success:  function(html) {
                    self.chooseBlock.html(html);
                    var input = self.chooseBlock.find('.geoip-popup-input');
                    self.autocomplete(input, self.chooseBlock.find('.geoip-body'));
                    input.siblings('ul.dropdown-menu').css({'maxHeight': 300, 'overflowY': 'auto', 'overflowX': 'hidden'});
                    input.focus();
                    self.citiesLoaded = true;
                    callback.apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

**Task:** It is necessary to call the function, i.e. call up a list of cities by clicking on the link in any part of the document

Trying to do this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="load-сities">ССЫЛКА</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#load-сities").click(function(e) {
    GeoIPModule.prototype.loadCities();
  });
</script>
```

But I get the error: **ReferenceError: GeoIPModule is not defined**

Complete script https://jsfiddle.net/3L604e7m

Comment: Can you please add bit more explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `GeoIPModule` to be globally available, you can set the property on the `window`. Currently, it is only visible inside the immediately-invoked function expression.

```
window.GeoIPModule = function(o, el){
  //...
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jctLh8bo/)

Comment: It Works. But now when i call GeoIPModule.prototype.loadCities(), i get "this.http_host" undefined error

Comment: I solved this error. I put **"this.http_host = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/';"** in **"GeoIPModule.prototype.loadCities = function()"**